# How can a mobile node be instructed to move in a particular trajectory?

Tags: networking, communication, unetstack

I want node A to send the details of the trajectory in which node B should move.

For example, I want node B to move to location [2.m,0,0] with a speed 1m/s. I will send a datagram with data [2,0,0,1]. Now how can node B extract the information from the received datagram to and change its trajectory accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

On node B, ensure that `mobility` is enabled, and the `location` and `origin` are set, so that you're in local coordinate systems in meters. If your coordinate system is not geo-referenced, you can set `origin` to `[NaN, NaN]`:

```
def node = agentForService org.arl.unet.Services.NODE_INFO

node.origin = [Float.NaN, Float.NaN]  // or GPS coordinates
node.location = [0, 0, 0]             // or wherever you want to start
node.mobility = true
```

Now, when you receive your datagram on node B, your agent can set the `node.speed` and `node.heading` to your desired speed and heading. For example:

```
node.heading = 90          // head East
node.speed = 1             // at 1 m/s
```

*In reality, you may want to compute the heading to your desired waypoint.*

Your agent can monitor the position of the node (perhaps using a `TickerBehavior`), and when it's time to stop (e.g. you've reached close enough to your way point `[2,0,0]`), set the speed to 0:

```
// if within 1 m of waypoint, stop
if (MathUtils.distance(node.location, [2,0,0] as double[]) < 1) {
  node.speed = 0
}
```