# How to dynamically calculate path for Node (USV) for connected 2-UAV which are surveying in orthogonal lawnmower pattern in simulation?

Tags: unetstack

I am writing a simulation script which involves 2-UUV and 1-USV. Both Underwater vehicle doing surveying in orthogonal lawnmower motion model. I would like to stay in the range of both vehicle, so they started at the same origin point. I want to know that How can define `USV` motion model in such a way that it is always in the communication range of both `UUV`'s for most of the time.

1. Basically How can I manually provide dynamic path planning/ motion model to `USV` so that I can communicate to both `UUV` most of the time ? Is it even possible ? Could someone provide a basic example of this or point me in the right direction ?

Here is my simulation script :

```
import org.arl.fjage.RealTimePlatform
import org.arl.unet.sim.MotionModel

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// display documentation

println '''
Bedford Basin AUV node network
------------------------------

Node USV-1: tcp://localhost:1101, http://localhost:8081/
Node UUV-1: tcp://localhost:1102, http://localhost:8082/
Node UUV-2: tcp://localhost:1103, http://localhost:8083/

------------------------------
------------------------------
'''

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// simulator configuration

platform = RealTimePlatform   // use real-time mode
// origin = [44.696178,-63.632992] // Bedford basin GPS co-ordinates 
origin = [44.434153,-63.251702]

simulate{
  def n1 = node 'USV', location: [0.m, -100.m,  1.8.m], heading: 45.deg, mobility: true, web: 8081, api: 1101, stack: "$home/etc/setup"
    n1.motionModel = MotionModel.lawnmower(speed: 0.5.mps, leg: 200.m, spacing: 50.m, legs: 17) 
                      
  def n2 = node 'UUV-1', location: [0.m,  0.m,  30.m], heading: 90.deg, mobility: true, web: 8082, api: 1102, stack: "$home/etc/setup"
    // n2.motionModel = MotionModel.lawnmower(speed: 3.3554.mps, leg: 6000.m, spacing: 40.m, legs: 150)
    n2.motionModel = MotionModel.lawnmower(speed: 0.3.mps, leg: 1000.m, spacing: 50.m, legs: 20)
  def n3 = node 'UUV-2', location: [0.m,  0.m,  30.m], heading: 180.deg, mobility: true, web: 8083, api: 1103, stack: "$home/etc/setup"
    //  n3.motionModel = MotionModel.lawnmower(speed: 3.3554.mps, leg: 6000.m, spacing: -40.m, heading:90.deg, legs: 150)
     n3.motionModel = MotionModel.lawnmower(speed: 0.3.mps, leg: 1000.m, spacing: -50.m, heading:90.deg, legs: 20)
}
```

2. How can I use `platform = DiscreteEventSimulator` with motion model ? If I want to simulate hours of simulation in smaller time ?

**Reference:**

1. "Path planning for cooperative underwater range-only navigation using a single beacon", [M.Chitre](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5547044?casa_token=myCFmvGfvOsAAAAA:ZhKaH2DJ9YI6oNcfGjdZmEVUbFsVGsO-VrymJcyCZqLVdmxLZoGylmf5Stv6YzGzQOCG-sMp)

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60080717/how-can-a-mobile-node-be-instructed-to-move-in-a-particular-trajectory/60186222#60186222

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Unet simulator supports multiple levels of motion models depending on the required complexity in the simulation.

The [NodeInfo](https://unetstack.net/handbook/unet-handbook_node_information.html) agent in each simulated node implements a basic dynamics model. The model is turned on using the `mobility` flag which can be set in a simulation script or directly on the `NodeInfo` agent. When `mobility` is enabled, the agent automatically updates `location` based on motion parameters such as `speed` and `heading`  using the simple dynamics model. This can be handy to simulate the motion of a node, for example, an AUV swimming away from an underwater modem.

We can easily do this by manually updating the parameters of one of the nodes in a simulation. Use the `2-node-network` example from Unet IDE. The "Map" view of the IDE is handy to visualize the motion of nodes. Connect to the WebShell of Node A and set the `mobility`, `heading`, and `speed` parameters. As the simulation continues the location of Node A will continue to be updated based on the `speed` and `heading`.

```
// On Node A's shell, set heading to 45deg and speed to 10m/s
node.mobility = true
node.heading = 45
node.speed = 10
```

[image: node]

For a more advanced use case, the Unet simulation scripts allow setting a series of Setpoints of motion parameters on a node. This is done using the `motionModel` parameter on the `node` Object in the simulation script. The [Unet Handbook has a few examples of this in Chapter 30](https://unetstack.net/handbook/unet-handbook_writing_simulation_scripts.html#_node_mobility).

Setting `motionModel` to a `List` of `Maps` with various motion properties for each of the Setpoint will automatically set the properties onto the `NodeInfo` agent for the specific simulated node at/for the appropriate time/duration. This in turn drives the dynamics model in `NodeInfo` giving the interpolated location between the Setpoints. For example, a node moving in a square can be simulated using this simulation script using 4 Setpoints. Note that the motion automatically stops after the last Setpoint.

```
def n = node 'B', location: [ 1.km, 0.km, -15.m], web: 8082, api: 1102, stack: "$home/etc/setup", mobility: true
n.motionModel = [
  [time:     0.minutes, heading:  0.deg, speed:   1.mps],
  [time:     1.minutes, heading:  -90.deg, speed: 1.mps],
  [time:     2.minutes, heading:  180.deg, speed: 1.mps],
  [time:     3.minutes, heading:  90.deg, speed:  1.mps],
]
```

[image: list]

The utility method `MotionModel.lawnmower` helps to generate this `List` for a set of Setpoint `Map` of properties for a lawnmower pattern of motion.

Finally, if even more fine-grained motion control is required, one can set the property `motionModel` of the simulated node to a Groovy [Closure](https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html). The `Closure` is called by the simulator with the current simulation timestamp and is expected to return a single Setpoint in form of a Groovy [Map](https://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#Collections-Maps). For example, a similar logic to a square pattern can be implemented with this `Closure` assigned to `motionModel`.

```
def n = node 'B', location: [ 1.km, 0.km, -15.m], web: 8082, api: 1102, stack: "$home/etc/setup", mobility: true
startTime = -1
n.motionModel = { ts -> 
  def setpoint = [speed: 10.mps, duration: 1.minutes]
  if (startTime < 0) startTime = ts
  if (ts <= startTime+1.minutes){
    setpoint["heading"] = 0.deg
  } else if (ts <= startTime+2.minutes){
    setpoint["heading"] = -90.deg
  } else if (ts <= startTime+3.minutes){
    setpoint["heading"] = 180.deg
  } else if (ts <= startTime+4.minutes){
    setpoint["heading"] = 90.deg
  } else {
    setpoint = [speed:0.mps]
  }
  return setpoint
}
```

[image: closure]

More complex logic can also be implemented inside such `Closures` including communicating with other Agents and even other nodes.

Finally, the `Closure` based approach can also allow one to override the builtin dynamics model in the `NodeInfo` agent by simply returning a Setpoint with a `location` property which will allow the location of the node to be updated directly from the `Closure` instead of going through the dynamics model.